Chrome extension keeps calling method over and over
My chrome extension keeps calling methods over and over again.
I have a method which check if a user is "logged in" (if they have some values saved in their local storage). This method should only be called once, but its calling my login api over and over again.
let tenant, UUID;
chrome.storage.local.get(['uuid'], result => {
  UUID = result?.uuid;
});

chrome.storage.managed.get("tenant", result => {
  tenant = result?.tenant;
});

const handleLogin = async () => {
  IP = await getPublicIP();

  if (tenant) {
     if (!UUID) {
        UUID = generateUUID();
        chrome.storage.local.set({ uuid: UUID });
      }
      login(UUID, "", "", "4"); //API CALL
    }
  }
} 

function checkLogin() {
  
  ...
  handleLogin();
  ...

}

checkLogin();


chrome.storage methods are asynchronous, so you must wait for them to complete before accessing tenant and UUID. See Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function?
